# I'm trying to install Ubuntu on my 32-bit Windows 7(ACER)

Tags: system-installation

I downloded the USB installation thing that Ubuntu released in 2012. Now I'm installing it and when it's 99% complete it shows an error like 'some file not found'

Answer (score 1):

Redownload the file and try again. Use the same method as last time to get the file on the USB. If it doesn't work, try a lower version of the linux distro your using.

The file your downloading may be corrupted, so try a different version or a different download location, if the above doesn't work.